# Pivot JSON then create an Array from Array of Arrays,

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I'm having difficulty generating a table in Angular2 from JSON because I want to pivot the JSON data and cant build an interface for it (the method i normally use)

An extract of the JSON im using is below which I convert which

```
[
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHAUD",
    "Holding": 318622.53
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHCAD",
    "Holding": 7195
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHEUR",
    "Holding": 5077.97
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHGBP",
    "Holding": 19625
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHJPY",
    "Holding": 16463
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHNZD",
    "Holding": 601.56
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHSGD",
    "Holding": 1000
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-26T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHUSD",
    "Holding": 1716906.25
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHAUD",
    "Holding": 318622.53
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHCAD",
    "Holding": 7195
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHEUR",
    "Holding": 5077.97
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHGBP",
    "Holding": 19625
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHJPY",
    "Holding": 16463
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHNZD",
    "Holding": 601.56
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHSGD",
    "Holding": 1000
  },
  {
    "ValueDate": "2017-04-27T14:16:00",
    "AccountName": "CASHUSD",
    "Holding": 1720781.25
  }
]
```

I used the following tutorial http://techbrij.com/convert-column-to-row-javascript-array-pivot to pivot the JSON array which results in an array of arrays

[image]

its not a bad result

headings are always at `[i][0]`
data is always at `[i + 1][j]`

Are there any ideas on a way I could loop through theses arrays to now create an object or another array which i could build a table from please?

Comment: So you have a list of objects that could be represented as a 2-dimensional  3xN array (N = number of objects) and you want to transform it to a Nx3 array - having variable number of columns. Is it so?

Comment: I believe this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array with three rows (representing ValueDate, AccountName and Holding values) and iterate over the original values:

```
source = [{...}, {...} ... ];
result = [[], [], []];
source.forEach((row, index) => {
  result[0][index] = row.ValueDate;
  result[1][index] = row.AccountName;
  result[2][index] = row.Holding;
});
```

See the following Plunker example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/15ZmVUxhEyPLTlDmHCLb?p=preview